# Substitute for transistor 2N3904 that is a SMD

Tags: transistors, surface-mount

I have the circuit shown below and one of the components (Q2) is a common through-hole transistor.  I'd like to replace this through hole device 2N3904 with a common SMD transistor that will do the same job so that my PCB manufacturer can solder these for me.

Does anyone have a recommendation?
[image: circuit]

Comment: asking for part recommendations is off topic here, but why aren't you just using an MMBT3904?

Comment: I understand my thinking was this transistor is so common that many may have the same issue

Comment: Surely you can find the SMD equivalent of a specific transistor without asking here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MMBT3904 is the same die. You should verify that the thermal performance is adequate, because it won't be as good as a TO-92.

The same part in SMD != doing the same job.

Comment: "the thermal performance [...] won't be as good as a TO-92" certainly makes it sound pitiful. Which I suppose it is!

Comment: @Hearth About 400°C/W compared to 200°C/W (depending on how much copper you spread around the collector lead it could be better though).

Comment: I would think an MMBT3904 could be used for anything a sensible designer would use a 2N3904 for, though. I at least would never use a '3904 for anything but switching low currents, due to its extremely poor thermal characteristics. Certainly not anything that would see significant power dissipation.

Comment: @Hearth People do strange things like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174223/class-a-single-transistor-amplifier-with-2n3904)

Comment: The part is being driven into saturation. Unless the relay is stupidly large, there should be no issue using the SOT-23 part.

Comment: @hacktastical Correct. To make the answer useful for others though, it's worth noting. I would probably put a beefier transistor in there just on principle, for switching an inductive load. The cost delta is pretty negligible (less than 0.2 cent in 50K).